# Is there anyway to make Plot.ly graphs html standalones?

Tags: python, plotly

I work almost exclusively with Python. My ideal pipeline is shown as below:

SQL > Python (pandas,numpy) > Plotly > Standalone HTML reports

So Python is used to handle the cruching from SQL and once the visual is compiled in my iPython Notebook, I'd like to share the standalone visuals via an attachment.

Possible? This is to make whatever visuals I want light and mobile. So it does not have to carry at scripts or data reading and display just the visual.

Bokeh allows standalone HTMLs, but Plotly will be an easier option for me.

Comment: I think plot.ly can generate images from the graphs

Comment: They definitely can, just that then it loses its interactivity which for me takes out the value in it.

Comment: So you're asking how to generate an *interactive* HTML report? I thought you were just looking for writing an HTML file containing the images from the graphs.

Comment: Yes, basically remain interactivity. Else will not need to do it in HTML.

Comment: Hmm, that would require some Javascript libraries in addition to the HTML. Personally, I would be satisfied with a static document of graphs as long as they are like bar charts or such

Comment: Plot.ly does however enables users to inject the js source files into iPython notebooks:
https://plot.ly/python/offline/

Just wondering whether there is a way for me to export it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offline plotly for python now supports offline standalone HTMLs using the plotly.offline.plot command.

Example from https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/

```
import plotly
print plotly.__version__  # version >1.9.4 required
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout
plotly.offline.plot({
"data": [
    Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 1, 3, 7])
],
"layout": Layout(
    title="hello world"
)
})
```

Much more to explore although I am facing challenges trying to figure out the functions and methods.

Answer (score 0):

https://plot.ly/python/html-reports/

Also use inline mode for plotting graphs without having an api key.

```
import plotly.offline as py
 # for inline graphs
 py.init_notebook_mode()
```